# I can't see my web address when I am typing it

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am the first one in my company that is trying to use Ubuntu 14.04 and somehow I have played around with something that has made my web address show up with a black box and I can't see what I am typing.  What would be the cause?

Comment: Graphical glitch maybe? A screenshot would be really helpful here.